# Memory Management Recursion Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, recursion

I am entering a recursion in Java with a large ArrayList. In one recursion step I split this list into two lists of half the size each and apply the same method recursively to both lists. However, since I do not need the large list any more after splitting it, I would like to delete it from memory. After searching here for a while, I came up with this:

```
public some_object recursiveMethod(ArrayList large_List) {
    //Compute the two sublists
    ArrayList lower_half = lowerHalf(large_List);
    ArrayList upper_half = upperHalf(large_List);

   //Delete large list from memory
   large_List = null;

   //Recursively call on smaller lists
   return procedure(recursiveMethod(lower_half),recursiveMethod(upper_half));
}
```

Will this work, i.e. will the GC remove the large list?

Comment: This might be not enough if there are other references to your large_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [divide & conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm). In such cases it is best do avoid local (hard) references (parameters and temporaries) and GC overhead alltogether by keeping that one, large list along with lightweight sub list views using [List.subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) (wrappers, referencing the large backing list) or a plain pair of indexes.

If these sublists must be modified independently from the original list, one may duplicate that large list once, before entering the recursive processing, which should still be more efficient than multiple independent sublist copies.

```
public some_object recursiveMethod(List large_List) {
    //Create views of the two sublists
    List lower_half = large_List.subList(0,large_List.size()/2);
    List upper_half = large_List.subList(large_List.size()/2,large_List.size());

   //Recursively call on list views
   return procedure(recursiveMethod(lower_half),recursiveMethod(upper_half));
}

public some_object recursiveMethod2(ArrayList large_List, int begin, int end) {
    //Create views of the two sublists
    int size = end - begin;
    int lowerBegin = begin;
    int lowerEnd = begin + size/2; //exclusive
    int upperBegin = lowerEnd;
    int upperEnd = begin + size; //exclusive

   //Recursively call on list views
   return procedure(recursiveMethod2(large_List,lowerBegin,lowerEnd),recursiveMethod2(large_List,upperBegin,upperEnd));
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I can not go with the List structure, but need the ArrayList Structure, since I need to find the median in the two sublists fast. From an ArrayList I can do this, but not from a List.

Comment: @Skrodde: You could pass down `large_List` along with pairs of start and end indexes. You may add the whole implementation of `recursiveMethod()` for clarity. - see edit

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, your approach seems best suitable for me. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because `lower_half` and `upper_class` are still referencing the list in the caller which doesn't unreference them until it has finished.

For example, take the first actual parameter of `procedure`: `recursiveMethod(lower_half)`.
`lower_half` **reference** is copied into called `recursiveMethod` `large_List` actual parameter. So you have the same list:

- Referenced at the caller as `lower_half`.
- And within the current call scope as `large_list`

In your current call you null the reference `large_list` but not caller's `lower_half`. Thus the list is still referenced somewhere and therefore not collected by the GC.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a way to achieve what I am heading for or is this simply not possible in Java?

Comment: Sorry, I can not follow. Do you suggest I make the attributes lower_half and upper_half global in the class? How would the recursion work then? Can you please give a short example? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. Although, to my understanding, shouldn't the calls of the recursiveMethod be placed right below the corresponding setting of the now global variables. In the way you put it, when the machine comes to the call "recursiveMethod(upper_half)", the upper_half variable will already be overwritten by the call of "recursiveMethod(lower_half)", won't it?

Comment: @Skrodde Yes, I ereased that solution suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why give up the old array and creating two smaller ones? Maybe it is possible to keep the array and just do a "virtual" dividing?

lowerHalf would give back an object which records start- and end-index in the array as your new virtual array.

That way you can divide the array without shuffleing around the contents...

```
public some_object recursiveMethod(ArrayList large_List, int start, int end) {
    //Compute the two sublists
    StartEndIndexObj lower_half = lowerHalf(large_List);
    StartEndIndexObj upper_half = upperHalf(large_List);

   //Recursively call on smaller lists
   return procedure(recursiveMethod(large_List, lower_half.start, lower_half.end),
                    recursiveMethod(large_List, upper_half.start, upper_half.end));
    }
```

Also see Sam's answer for a version with List.subList.

Comment: By the way... Is it strange that I sometimes turn to the "manual" way of doing things, because we had no other way back in the pascal & c days, instead of using library solutions? I'm getting old...

Comment: Sadly, the "lowerHalf" and "upperHalf" are more complicated than this. The corresponding values are arbitrarily scattered over the "large_List". Following your approach I would indeed need to rearrange (in the worst case) all elements in the large_List.

Comment: maybe you can use a different data structure, something like a balanced tree? you could "reuse" the content objects and you would also have direct access to the "middle"... You could even retain a count for a size, while building the tree...

Comment: Wikipedia entry about self balancing tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Answer (score 0):

The GC will remove all objects without a reference. How ever, this works NOT with all JVM. I'm not 100 percent shore if you have a JVM with a GC.

Comment: But `large_List` is referenced by either `upper_half` or `Lower_half` in it's previous recursion so it cannot be recycled until the previous recursive method is finished.

Comment: Is there a JVM without a GC?